# Почему блок "footer" не отображает своего размера?

Tags: html, css

Почему `footer` показывает только отступы, а сам не имеет размера, хотя в нём находятся элементы.
Что нужно поправить?

[Вот сайт](http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a/category-level3a.html)
или скрин:
[image: изображение]
[сайт](http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a/category-level3a.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что все элементы внутри него либо `float: left;`, либо `float: right;`.
А для таких элементов браузер игнорирует высоту, а следолвательно у содержимого `footer` высоты нет.
А видимая высота у Вашего `footer` потому что у него есть `padding`.

Лучше у `div.links` заменить `float` на `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;`